# How to use Validate an email in selenium using MailAddress and Try Catch

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to c# so apologise if you see basic errors. I want to validate an email address and I am using a public bool, try catch and then a public void. I want to retrieve the email text from the relevant HTML which I have been able to do and then validate that it is a valid email using 'MailAddress'.

The problem is that it is throwing an exception:

```
  throw new Exception("email within booking confirmation summary is not valid");
```

I think I am using the code incorrectly but can somebody guide me in what I need to do in the code to ensure I am correctly validating the email as I believe I have some code I don't need. Below is the code:

```
 public static bool IsEmail(string emailToValidate)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailToValidate))
            return true;

        try
        {
            new MailAddress(emailToValidate);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void CheckEmailDisplayed()
    {
        var email = _driver.FindElement(ConfirmationResponsiveElements.ViewEmail);
        var emailText = email.Text;

        if (IsEmail(emailText))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("email is valid");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("email within booking confirmation summary is not valid");
        }
```

ViewEmail is pointing to a HTML tag below:

```
 public static By ViewEmail => By.ClassName("confirmation-banner__text");
```

Thanks

Comment: You're throwing an exception if it's not a valid email address. If you don't want to throw an exception, then don't throw one!

Comment: yes but it should be valid so it shouldn't throw one, or that's what i was hoping for :)

Comment: Well you haven't shown us your input.

Comment: This is the input: 'We've sent an email to yourname@gmail.com confirming your booking'

Comment: That's not a valid email address. That's a sentence. You'd have to send in just `yourname@gmail.com` if you want your function to correctly validate it. Or rewrite it so that it checks the whole string to see if at least one valid email address is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below :-

```
bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    try
    {
        return new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email).Address == email;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

OR

Use this single liner method -

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public bool IsValidEmail(string source)
{
    return new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(source);
}
```

OR

.net 4.5 added [ions.EmaSystem.ComponentModel.DataAnnotatilAddressAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute.aspx)

You can browse the [EmailAddressAttribute's source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs,54), this is the Regex it uses internally:

```
const string pattern = @"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$";
```

OR

```
public static bool emailIsValid(string email)
{
    string expression = "\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*";
    if (Regex.IsMatch(email, expression))
    {
        return Regex.Replace(email, expression, string.Empty).Length == 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Just be careful with regex. The `EmailAddressAttribute` regex fails on "`example@localhost`" (but seems to do pretty well otherwise) and that last regex fails on more valid addresses such as "`#!$%&'*+-/=?^_\`{}|~@example.org`" (I've set up a VM before with local&user account named \` to send mail. Uh, because you can.)